# How to create a boxplot in R with different characters to identify moderate and extreme outliers?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I would like to create a boxplot in R with moderate (o; <= Q1-1.5IQR; >= Q3+1.5IQR) and extreme/severe (*; <= Q1-3IQR; >= Q3+3IQR) outliers identified differently. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved an elegant solution:

```
 y <- c(-4,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,12,16,26)
par(bty = 'n',mar = c(0,2,0,0))


bp <-boxplot(x = y, plot=FALSE,ylab="x",mgp = c(3, 3, 0),axes=FALSE)

#ii) Plot the boxplot, suppressing points with outpch=NA.
bxp(bp, outpch=NA)

bxp.extreme<-function(z, extreme=3.5) {
    boxrange <- bp$stats[4,bp$group] - bp$stats[2,bp$group] 
    big.outlier<- (z$out >=  bp$stats[4,bp$group] + extreme*boxrange) |
        (z$out <=  bp$stats[2,bp$group] - extreme*boxrange) 
    return(big.outlier)
}

ext<-bxp.extreme(bp)
points(bp$group, bp$out, pch=ifelse(ext, 8,1), col=ifelse(ext, 1,1))


legend(title = "Outliers","topright", bty="0", legend=c(expression(atop("Q"[1]*"-1.5IQR ≤ Moderate ≤ Q"[3]*"-3IQR","Q"[3]*"+1.5IQR ≤ Moderate ≤ Q"[3]*"+3IQR")),
                                                        expression(atop("Extreme ≤ Q"[1]*"-3IQR","Extreme ≥ Q"[3]*"+3IQR"))),
       pch=c(1,8), col=c(1,1),y.intersp=1.5)
```

[image: Boxplot with moderate and extreme outliers]

I used the code found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-August/401677.html) and adapted it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the `range` argument and add another boxplot on top of the first. But it's difficult to suppress specific outliers, so instead of a * for the extreme outliers, I've filled in the default O (`pch`=1) with `pch`=20.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rt(200, df=3)

boxplot(x, outcol="red")
boxplot(x, add=TRUE, range=3, pars=list(outpch=20, outcol="red", whisklty=0, staplelty=0))
```

[image]

If you really wanted asterisks, you can make them much larger so that they totally obscure the previous circles (moderate outliers).

```
boxplot(x, outcol="red")
boxplot(x, add=TRUE, range=3, 
        pars=list(outpch='*', outcol="red", outcex=3, whisklty=0, staplelty=0))
```

[image]